# Searchable/filterable treeview

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm searching for a treeview with a textbox where I can put a searchcriteria in it. Then the treeview should be filtered and only the matched elements should be shown.

Can anyone point me to a plugin for this? I tried making the treeview myself. When the treeview is only 2 levels deep it kinda works. But it should also work when the treeview is for example 10 levels deep.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) does all these pretty well.